# What is Exit Code 13?

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently installed Eclipse for my laptop at home, Whenever I run it, I get an error message with exit code 13; Eclipse does open but exits immediately. What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java (or the other way round). They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Comment: Do I have to have the same-bit for Java?